# Why are constraints disabled in sqlite by default?

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

You have to run `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON` to enable it.

Why? Is it because this feature is buggy in sqlite? I'm asking because I'm encountering issues with data integrity. I get"Integrity constraint violation" errors sometimes when it shouldn't be happening.

Comment: it's probably a performance feature. Requiring you to opt in to foreign key check overhead.

Comment: The feature is also relatively new (introduced end of 2009). There was no such thing before, constraints were ignored, so the default makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not buggy. It's just that many users do not need strict constraints. SQLite is [one of the most tested](https://www.sqlite.org/testing.html) pieces of software out there

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html):

> Foreign key constraints are disabled by default (for backwards
>   compatibility), so must be enabled separately for each database
>   connection separately.